# Windows 8 extreme lags

Tags: windows-8

The system hangs like all CPU cores are busy but nothing is actually running (at least I'm not aware of it). It feels like the screen is updated once a minute or so, I can't even log in to the system now (after many reboots)! What the heck could this be?

The last thing I remember is that I've installed AMD CodeAnalyst, and about a couple of minutes later Windows hanged (but not completely though, I even managed to start the Task Manager and kill all running apps that didn't help).

Comment: You should try to return to a previous restore point and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: @JasjeevSingh: This fixed it, thanks (used a bootable USB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try returning to a previous restore point.

Steps to open *System Restore*:

1. Move your mouse cursor the the upper-right corner of the screen.
2. Enter **Recovery** in the search field.
3. Click **Settings → Recovery → Open System Restore**.

Comment: @Dennis The OP confirmed that this was the solution to their problem. In that case it's okay to stay as an answer.

Comment: @Dennis how do you know OP is using Windows 8?

Comment: The question's title is *Windows 8 extreme lags* and the question is tagged as *windows-8*.

Comment: Kill me. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

Save all task info at external drive:

```
tasklist /V > <drive letter>:\pr.txt
wmic process get commandline, processid >> <drive letter>:\pr.txt
```

For example:

```
tasklist /V > R:\pr.txt
wmic process get commandline, processid >> R:\pr.txt
```

Kill all tasks:

```
TASKKILL /F /T /FI "USERNAME ne NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
```

After this command, you will have 30 seconds to reboot. It needs to be quickly undone. Press `Alt+Ctrl+Esc` and go to Task Manager.

Run as administrator:

```
shutdown /a
```

This command cancels the reboot.

Run Notepad, `regedit /m`, `cmd` as administrator.

Comment: @slhck I don't get the connection between the youtube video and his answer O_o

Comment: @nixda test `TASKKILL /F /T /FI "USERNAME ne NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"` )))

Comment: This will kill all tasks. And you try to compare this with a grenade? Hmm, I don't know.

Comment: @nixda Me neither. STTR, can you please not put random … things into your posts? Thank you.

Comment: @nixda In fact, with running second in an unusual setting.

Comment: @slhck Thank you so much, that change my strange and misspelled messages. But accidents are not accidental. And sometimes, too, you can laugh.) I think that is part of me. Probably not, and thank you for your patience.